# Create both Spanned and Striped Volume from same HDDs

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a DAS with 5 HDDs connected to my Windows PC in a striped configuration (each drive shows as an individual drive)

Is there some way to show them both as a striped configuration (like it is now) AND another SPANNED volume (one drive with all the content)?

Aim: I want to data to be stored as is, but when i want to read data, I'd have to only pick the spanned drive.

Comment: How would you determine on which HDD a given file is stored?

Comment: that where the striped configuration is essential.. using that to write data.